# What are "Unassigned" slots for in "Brand Assets" in "Assets.xcassets" in Xcode 7.3.1?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, assets

After clicking the "Migrate" button on the Target > General > Deployment Info > App icons and Launch images > Launch Images Source panel, Xcode 7.3.1 created yet another item in my Assets.xcassets: `Brand Assets`.

This item has 6 slots:

- 4 of those slots are a pair for `iPad Portrait iOS 7-9` and another pair for `iPad Landscape iOS 7-9`. I dutifully copied in images I already had in the "LaunchItem" item in the same Assets.xcassets (seems redundant, but whatever Xcode wants Xcode gets).
- 2 of those slots are a pair labeled `Unassigned`.

Now when I build I get an Issue warning:

> file:///Users/…/Assets.xcassets/: warning: Ambiguous Content: The launch image set "Brand Assets" has 2 unassigned children.

- What are those "Unassigned" slots for?
- What should I do with them to make Xcode happy?

[image]

Comment: I just deleted them by right clicking on each of them and selecting "Remove Selected Items", but I have no idea if that's the correct thing to do.